# How to delete GENERAL CATEGORY in Galereya jquery image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, categories

I don't want all of my images together when I open this gallery.

I want it to open a **specific category** when I load the page.

For example: now I have a general category named ALL (with categories: Architecture, Portraits, Street...). I want instead of general category ALL to be one of these categories (when I open this page)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familar with Galereya jquery but I think this might do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var gallery = $('#gal').galereya();     //make it a gallery
    gallery.openSlider(5);                  //show 5 items
    gallery.changeCategory("catagoryName"); //change gallery catagory

});
```

Comment: http://vodkabears.github.io/galereya/demo.html When you open this demo page it opens All categories: Photography, Drawing, Handmade, Street Art, Digital. I want instead of All to be for example Photography

Comment: Ok so you should be able to change `"catagoryName"` in my answer to `"Photography"` and it will load the page with the changed category.